# Wordpress contact page, google maps not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I have a wordpress site with a contact page. In that contact page there is a google maps container. But that container doesn't show any google maps data.

Code:

```
<div id="map" class="imgbox">
          <?php echo do_shortcode('[gmap width="424" height="246" latitude="'.$info_latitude.'" longitude="'.$info_longitude.'"  controls="true" zoomcontrol="true" zoom="15" html="'.$info_address.'" popup="true"]');?>
        </div>
```

I know I can embed google maps there. But there must be something in the theme settings where I can set the google maps latitute and longitude.

Theme i'm using is 'Ecobiz'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it.

The $info_latitude and $info_longitude didn't pass any data into the file.